# How to connect to Google Cloud SQL from a GCE pod?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine

What's the best way to connect to a google cloud SQL DB from a google container engine pod? The doc implies I should request an IPV4 address for the DB and connect through that.

I wonder whether there's a better way using the DB's name instead?

Is there something similar to using the `/cloudsql/<db_name>` socket connection in App Engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the best answer, but you could always [set up a DNS name](https://cloud.google.com/dns/getting-started) for it.

I don't know whether there's any built-in way to use the name instead of the IP. App Engine can do special nice things for you because it runs your code in a specially managed run-time environment.

Comment: Thanks. This sounds better than using the raw IP. I still hope they will come up with a better way of doing this.